# Replacing GNOME with KDE on openSUSE

Tags: gnome, kde, opensuse, desktop-environment

I was on `openSUSE Leap 15`. I was using GNOME desktop environment. I installed KDE Plasma with this method:

https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:KDE_install

After installing KDE Plasma, I also upgraded my Leap 15 to Tumbleweed with these instructions:

https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Tumbleweed_upgrade

I have already edited these files, and replaced `Gdm` with `Kdm` and `Gnome` with `Plasma5`:

```
me@linux-iwyn:~> sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/windowmanager 
me@linux-iwyn:~> sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/displaymanager
```

Now, I have `openSUSE Tumbleweed` and I login with KDE Plasma desktop environment. However, I am observing that gdm and gnome-related stuff are still all over my system:

```
me@linux-iwyn:~> ps -aux |grep gdm
root      1877  0.0  0.1 267204  9476 ?        Sl   09:29   0:00 /usr/sbin/gdm
root      2136  0.0  0.1 216268  8224 ?        Sl   09:29   0:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-launch-environment]
gdm       2187  0.0  0.0  46436  7940 ?        Ss   09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --user
gdm       2191  0.0  0.0  75584  3168 ?        S    09:29   0:00 (sd-pam)
gdm       2203  0.0  0.0 173016  7000 tty7     Ssl+ 09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-wayland-session gnome-session --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
gdm       2208  0.0  0.0  32120  4832 ?        Ss   09:29   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
gdm       2287  0.0  0.1 497608 14264 tty7     Sl+  09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
gdm       2294  0.5  1.2 3360088 103272 tty7   Sl+  09:29   0:48 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
gdm       2316  0.0  0.3 534280 32052 tty7     Sl+  09:29   0:00 /usr/bin/Xwayland :1024 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -auth /run/user/462/mutter/Xauthority -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6
gdm       2323  0.0  0.0 324688  5704 ?        Ssl  09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2/at-spi-bus-launcher
gdm       2328  0.0  0.0  31528  4308 ?        S    09:29   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
gdm       2330  0.0  0.0 194372  6360 ?        Sl   09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
gdm       2336  0.0  0.1 1378956 9336 ?        S<l  09:29   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
gdm       2342  0.0  0.0  55380  5492 ?        S    09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/pulse/gconf-helper
gdm       2344  0.0  0.0  41020  5412 ?        S    09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/GConf/2/gconfd-2
gdm       2358  0.0  0.0 328392  6884 tty7     Sl   09:29   0:00 ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable
gdm       2361  0.0  0.0 256016  7380 tty7     Sl   09:29   0:00 /usr/lib64/ibus/ibus-dconf
gdm       2366  0.0  0.3 372228 25120 tty7     Sl   09:29   0:00 /usr/lib64/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
gdm       2371  0.0  0.0 253828  5696 ?        Sl   09:29   0:00 /usr/lib64/ibus/ibus-portal
gdm       2376  0.0  0.0 246768  3792 ?        Ssl  09:29   0:00 /usr/lib/xdg-permission-store
gdm       2385  0.0  0.3 524220 27200 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-xsettings
gdm       2390  0.0  0.0 251344  7236 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-a11y-settings
gdm       2391  0.0  0.3 371788 24380 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-clipboard
gdm       2392  0.0  0.3 686696 28120 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-color
gdm       2395  0.0  0.1 287940 11752 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-datetime
gdm       2400  0.0  0.0 252796  5496 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-housekeeping
gdm       2401  0.0  0.3 521592 24432 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-keyboard
gdm       2402  0.0  0.3 1088976 28372 tty7    Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-media-keys
gdm       2414  0.0  0.0 175176  5008 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-mouse
gdm       2415  0.0  0.3 814904 27108 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-power
gdm       2416  0.0  0.1 232464  8148 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-print-notifications
gdm       2419  0.0  0.0 175192  5024 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-rfkill
gdm       2421  0.0  0.0 249036  5132 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-screensaver-proxy
gdm       2423  0.0  0.0 254376  5468 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-sharing
gdm       2429  0.0  0.0 408220  6812 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-smartcard
gdm       2437  0.0  0.1 287500 10880 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-sound
gdm       2440  0.0  0.3 454888 25528 tty7     Sl+  09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon-3.0/gsd-wacom
gdm       2500  0.0  0.0 256192  6112 tty7     Sl   09:30   0:00 /usr/lib64/ibus/ibus-engine-simple
gdm       2560  0.0  0.0 171412  4632 ?        Sl   09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf-service
root      2785  0.0  0.1 218372  8516 ?        Sl   09:30   0:00 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]
m3g1dd    2804  0.0  0.0 187560  6092 tty2     Ssl+ 09:30   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session --run-script /usr/bin/startkde
m3g1dd    2806 10.0  1.0 392448 82492 tty2     Sl+  09:30  14:56 /usr/bin/X vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
m3g1dd   28944  0.0  0.0   6688   828 pts/3    S+   11:59   0:00 grep --color=auto gdm
```

I wonder how I can totally get rid of Gnome/Gdm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use zypper to look for gnome patterns and remove them, like:

```
sudo zypper -n rm patterns-openSUSE-gnome gnome-*
```

Comment: Thanks ☺ eventually I installed openSUSE Leap 15 with KDE as the desktop environment